# Entity Framework 5 with MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

I am building a website with a rather complex `SQL` database.
I made a `Query` class, which holds multiple primitive fields (which all work fine) and also multiple `List<SomeType>`. `SomeType` is also defined under the `Models` folder in my solution. It also holds single instances of `SomeType`. Then, I made a `QueryDBContext` class which inherits `DbContext`.

I have a `Generate` function which receives a string and creates a fully formed `Query` instance. If I immediately send it to my `View` - it works fine. But if I store it in my `DB` - only the primitive values are kept, and the reference types (both `Lists<SomeType>` and `SomeType`) are `null`.

I believe the problem is that EF doesn't support reference types - or maybe I need something special for this case?
Here's `Query`

```
public class Query
{
    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }

    public SomeType Base { get; set; }
    public List<SomeType> Derived { get; set; }
    //more of these

    public string SmallGraphImage { get; set; }
    public string MediumGraphImage { get; set; }
    public string LargeGraphImage { get; set; }
}
public class QueriesDBContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Query> Queries { get; set; }
}
```

Here's `SomeType`

```
public class SomeType
{
    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string ExpandedOutForm { get; set; }
    public string ExpandedInForm { get; set; }
    //more strings
}
```

Note: The database works fine for primitives. For developing purposes, I made a `Controller` which deletes & rebuilds the database for each modification. I also tried replacing `List` with `IList`.

If EF doesn't support reference types, what should I do? Will it work on `structs` ? How can I store `Lists` inside a database entry? (Yeah, I could store it in another table with its ID - but I believe EF has a more elegant solution for this)

Comment: You can't store Lists inside a database field.  A database field can hold a value but not an array of values.  If you need to have a reference to an array of values from a parent items, you are basically talking about having a One to many reference.

Comment: So, how can I do a one-to-many reference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I believe the problem is that EF doesn't support reference types

The Entity Framework does support reference types. With the default configuration those will be mapped to a seperate database table. In your case, a Query_id column will be added to the table 'SomeTypes'. The Entity Framework will use those to create SQL Joins when loading data.

The reason why your properties are showing as `NULL` has nothing to do with this. It has to do with how the Entity Framework loads data. By default, EF will not load a whole object graph from the start. This would mean that if your `SomeType` references another class which references another... and you would load the whole database in one call.

You have two options:

- [Explicitly loading the references](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg671236%28v=vs.103%29.aspx). You tell the Entity Framework which properties you are going to use in advance and it will load them in one call from the database.

  Query c = ctx.Queries
  .Include(x => x.Derived)
  .Include(x => x.Base).First();

Here you use the `Include` method to tell the Entity Framework to load both your `Derived` collection as your `Base` property.

- Use lazy loading. This means that the Entity Framework will load your property when it's needed. For this to work, EF creates a proxy class that wraps your class and will execute the database calls just in time.

  For this to work, you will need to declare your `public SomeType Base { get; set; }` as virtual so EF can create a proxy and intercept those calls.

The only reason you where not seeing your data, is because it wasn't loaded from the database.

Answer (score 1):

> I believe the problem is that EF doesn't support reference types

EF supports reference types - they're essentially mapped to other tables.

> (Yeah, I could store it in another table with its ID - but I believe EF has a more elegant solution for this)

Actually that'e *exactly* how EF handles 1-many relationships by default.  How are you intending to store those in a single table?

Comment: Of course EF stores then in different tables *internally*, my question is: how to rewrite my class structure so it will work? edit:So EF will create the appropriate DB and save the results...